# AWS login with facebook in swift: Stuck at -> continueWithBlock:self.completionHandler

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, facebook, amazon-web-services

I am a Beginner to swift/objective.

I am working on AWS login with facebook. Using the following:
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/blob/master/CognitoSync-Sample/Objective-C/CognitoSyncDemo/AmazonClientManager.m

```
[[task continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {
        if(!task.error){
            //if we have a new device token register it
            __block NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            __block NSData *currentDeviceToken = [userDefaults objectForKey:DeviceTokenKey];
            __block NSString *currentDeviceTokenString = (currentDeviceToken == nil)? nil : [currentDeviceToken base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
            if(currentDeviceToken != nil && ![currentDeviceTokenString isEqualToString:[userDefaults stringForKey:CognitoDeviceTokenKey]]){
                [[[AWSCognito defaultCognito] registerDevice:currentDeviceToken] continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {
                    if(!task.error){
                        [userDefaults setObject:currentDeviceTokenString forKey:CognitoDeviceTokenKey];
                        [userDefaults synchronize];
                    }
                    return nil;
                }];
            }
        }
        return task;
    }] continueWithBlock:self.completionHandler];
```

My code is in swift.
I am stuck with converting the last line of code to swift:

```
task?.continueWithBlock {
            (task: AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in
            if (task.error != nil) {
                let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
                let currentDeviceToken: NSData? = userDefaults.objectForKey(Constants.DEVICE_TOKEN_KEY) as? NSData
                var currentDeviceTokenString : String

                if currentDeviceToken != nil {
                    currentDeviceTokenString = currentDeviceToken!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
                } else {
                    currentDeviceTokenString = ""
                }
                if currentDeviceToken != nil && currentDeviceTokenString != userDefaults.stringForKey(Constants.COGNITO_DEVICE_TOKEN_KEY) {

                    AWSCognito.defaultCognito().registerDevice(currentDeviceToken).continueWithBlock { (task: AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in
                        if (task.error == nil) {
                            userDefaults.setObject(currentDeviceTokenString, forKey: Constants.COGNITO_DEVICE_TOKEN_KEY)
                            userDefaults.synchronize()
                        }
                        print("Inside If")
                        return nil
                    }
                }
            }
            self.returnUserData()
            return task
            }.continueWithBlock(self.completionHandler)
```

The last line shows error: "Value of optional type AWSContinuationBlock? not unwrapped.

When I try fixing it via continueWithBlock(self.completionHandler!), it gives run time error : "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" 
Can somebody please help?

Comment: i think this could be because your completionHandler property is nil.. have you assigned a block to it? if a block is nil and you invoke it, app will crash..

Comment: Yes it's nil. Can I just remove this statement. How would it affect the code?

Comment: try making an empty block and assigning that to completionHandler before this line of code executes...